# Vector Bearing Force

Tags: trigonometry

I have a Vector bearing question for StackExchange.

A Force of 11 pounds and a force of 6 pounds act on an object at an angle of $41 ^\circ$ with respect to one another. What is the magnitude of the resulatant force and what angle does the resultant force form with the 11 pound force.

Well of course i tried it but somethings telling me im wrong here.

Illustration i made(may be wrong):

```
  6 pounds
   __________
   /       /
11/       /
 /       / 11 pounds
/_______/
6 pounds
```

Picture of illustration:
[image]

So What i did was:

**Magnitude**

\begin{align}
\left\lVert x \right\rVert = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 -2ab * cos(C)} \\
 & = \sqrt{11^2 + 6^2 - 2*6*11 * cos(41 ^\circ)} \\ 
 & = 57.37pounds \\
\end{align}

That above i am not very confident of an anwser of. i feel like i messud up somewhere.

For the angle i can just do the same cosine law after i get size.

### EDIT

\begin{align}
\left\lVert x \right\rVert = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 -2ab * cos(C)} \\
 & = \sqrt{11^2 + 6^2 - 2*6*11 * cos(139 ^\circ)} \\ 
 & = 16.01 pounds\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues:

- You so not seem to have taken the square root
- the angle is in fact $139^\circ$

Comment: I didnt take the sqrt? yea i did. Angle is 139?

Comment: What is $11^2 + 6^2 - 2\times 6\times 11 \times  \cos(41 ^\circ)$? What is the angle opposite $X$?

Comment: Hmm Henry.. ok so if i change that Cos to 139.. im all good?

Comment: Your answer should be less than $11+6$, but not much less, so if it is not about $16$ it may be wrong

Comment: Hmm henry ima edit my problem so you see my progress so far!

Comment: Ok I Edited.. now i have 16.01 Pounds

Comment: I get the same value

Comment: Hmm.. and now i am stubled upon how to find angle! If you could give me a hint that would be great!